# How to run a newly built Intellij-Community version, Run command is currently disabled

Tags: intellij-idea

I just built a Intellij-Community version of Intellij, but run command is disabled.  I believe I need a configuration file in order for the run command to be enabled.  According to the documentation at [Checkout and Build Community](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/checkout_and_build_community.html)

> To run the code, use the IDEA shared run configuration provided by the project.

Where is this file?, doesn't seem to be available in run ~ edit configuration. or how can I create one?

Comment: Wrong.  You have to edit configuration and then tell IntelliJ what kind of application you want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme file has configuration details that compile Intellij-Community correctly.  Both JDK 1.6 and 1.8 are used.  This then allows you to see IDEA run configuration file.

> Configure a JSDK named "IDEA jdk" (case sensitive), pointing to an installation of JDK 1.6.

Unless you're running on a Mac with an Apple JDK, add /lib/tools.jar to the set of "IDEA jdk" jars.

> Configure a JSDK named "1.8", pointing to an installation of JDK 1.8.
>
> Add /lib/tools.jar to the set of "1.8" jars.

Comment: Yes, but since I just getting up to speed on Intellij itself, I have no idea what the contents of the edit configuration should be to run my newly build version of Intellij-Community.  Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Depends on the type of project. If it's a simple java program you can simply define the main class (the main you want to launch the program with).

Comment: The project is INTELLIJ-COMMUNITY itself.

Comment: I can't advise you on that specific project. Is it a maven build? Can you tell which class is the "Starter" for it. If you find it follow my advice after the list. @PeterBirdsall

Comment: @PeterBirdsall, did you read the [readme](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/README.md) on the repo?

Comment: Will check to see if I can find the 'Starter' for it.  I was using Intellij website, will look for the infamous readme file.

Comment: I linked to it in the comment in case you missed it. @PeterBirdsall

Comment: Missed that, checking it out. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Run->Edit Configurations and then tell IntelliJ what kind of application you want to run:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but like in the comments below, WHAT is to be defined for Intellij-Community?